# MongoDB array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

The problem I am facing is below:

I have a MongoDB document whose structure is as follows

```
"name": "XYZ",
"array":[
 {
  "value": "Alpha"
 },
 {
  "value": "Beta"
 },
 {
  "value": "Alpha"
 },
]
```

and I have to count how many objects have value Alpha.
I have tried the following two queries but both only give me value 1.

```
db.current_database.find({array: {$elemMatch: {value: "Alpha"}}}).count()
db.current_database.find({'array.value': 'Alpha'}).count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` collection method returns documents, not fragments.

A few options to count occurrances of elements in an array:

Most languages provide a method to filter/reduce/count elements in an array, so this should be fairly straightforward on the client side.

The MongoDB aggregation framework provides `$reduce`, `$filter`, `$size`, `$group`, `$unwind`, and a few other operators that might be useful in this situation.

One possible solution using `$reduce`:

```
db.current_database.aggregate([
  {$match: {"array.value": "Alpha"}},
  {$addFields:{
      count: {
          $reduce: {
              input: "$array",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: {$eq: ["$$this.value", "Alpha"]},
                     then: {$sum: ["$$value", 1]},   
                     else: "$$value"
                  }
               }
           }
       }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I get error "2020-09-17T13:02:19.163-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: value",
        "code" : 17276,
        "codeName" : "Location17276"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:536:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:620:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
@(shell):1:1"

Comment: How does your test run differ from https://mongoplayground.net/p/fIJmJxuFJfR?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just messed up with keyword "value". Now, this does return a document, how can one just get a value.

Comment: All mongodb queries and commands return a document or cursor.   You can use `$project` to limit which fields are returned.  The driver or shell may have  convenience functions to show the value of one field.  For instance, adding `.next().count` to that sample query in the shell will return just the value of the `count` field from the first document.